# clientidentifier in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using the spring Configuration of a  Connection Preparer, where i have a requirement to set the client identifier for every connection obtained and that can be used in the database policies. Here i have a issue when multiple requests are coming parallel it is getting messed up due to the user name passing to the connection preparer that i am using .

i am exactly following the link given below from spring by using the spring jar.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.connection.html
The one extra thing that i am doing is having a variable username in my client identifier class and have a setter and getter methods and invoke this as a parameter to the stored procedure.

My problem is when there are parallel transactions  the client identifier singleton bean that is injected is having a old copy of the username that i have passed.

Is there any other better option to set a dynamic method to pass the username from the request to this bean and while retrieving the bean it should return the correct values.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a utility (static variables/methods) class with a ThreadLocal variable. Provide getter and setter.
2. Create a filter that gets the user from the request. Set this user to the thread-local created above.
3. Call the getter anytime/anywhere (E.g. when building 'prepSql' before invoking callable statement in the [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.connection.html) you have referenced).